# dp.chat_join_request.register does not work

Tags: python, telegram, chat, aiogram

I have created a handler to display information about adding a user to a chat/channel

```
async def channel(update: ChatJoinRequest, bot: Bot):
    print(update)
```

And added it to dp via register

```
dp.chat_join_request.register(channel)
```

But the bot does not respond either to joining the chat or to joining the channel. The bot is an admin

Answer (score 0):

I tested it and when user send request to join, handler receive event.
May be you want to receive event when user joining to channel/chat without request? So you can use `chat_member` event instead `chat_join_request` [(docs)](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/dispatcher/filters/chat_member_updated.html).